# Why are split and join results are different?

Tags: javascript

I used split and join to swap latitude and longitude of the coordinates. I am using leaflet to get the coordinates and as polyline, swapping coordinates works just fine but when I do it using marker, the last digit of the latitude and first digit of longitude is gone
This is the code, as you can see they're just the same code

```
if (type === 'polyline') {
    const res = ["[" +
      tmp.map(
        x => '[' +
        swapLatLon(
          stripFirstLast(x).split(', ')
        ).join(', ') +
        ']'
      ).join(', ') +
      "]"
    ];
  document.getElementById("polyline").value = res;
} else if (type === 'marker') {
    const res = ["[" +
      tmp.map(
        x => '[' +
        swapLatLon(
          stripFirstLast(x).split(', ')
        ).join(', ') +
        ']'
      ).join(', ') +
      "]"
    ];
  document.getElementById("marker").value = res;
} else {
  console.log('__undefined__');
}
```

This is a sample result for `res`

> Original: [37.0902, 95.7129]
> Expectation: [[95.7129, 37.0902]]
> Reality: [[95.712, 7.0902]]

Comment: Why is this tagged with `php`? There's only JavaScript in your question.

Comment: What's that `stripFirstLast(x)` doing?

Comment: To help you we would need to see the inputs (tmp etc.) and the contents of the functions used, particularly `stripFirstLast`

Comment: tmp = [37.0902, 95.7129], res = [[95.712, 7.0902]]

Comment: Iif it's just the same line of code, why are you duplicating it?

Comment: Can you show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ? You can also provide a snippet to better understand the error

Comment: It looks like `stripFirstLast` takes a number as an argument, and converts that to a string and removes the first and last character. Maybe you should use `toString` instead of `stripFirstLast`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` and `join` are inverses of each other. It is likely that the issue is elsewhere in the data processing.

In any case, here is a direct one line solution using the data examples that you provided:

```
x = "[37.0902, 95.7129]"
swapped = "[" + x.slice(1,-1).split(", ").reverse().join(", ") + "]"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to swap places of two variables in an array, then use [deconstructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
const tmp = [37.0902, 95.7129]
let [long, lat] = tmp;
let res = [[lat, long]];
let type;

if (type === 'polyline') {
  document.getElementById("polyline").value = res;
} else if (type === 'marker') {
  document.getElementById("marker").value = res;
} else {
  console.log('__undefined__');
}

console.log({tmp})
console.log({res})
```